# Capturing output and input of interactive program with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm working on automating an interactive command line Java program in bash to validate that the program produces proper output for the input (basically poor-man's unit testing in bash).

For example, if I have a java program that asks the user to enter their full name, and then outputs only their first name, it should look something like this:

```
Enter your name: John Doe
John
```

Where "John Doe" was typed in by the user.

A simple bash command to run this might look like this:

```
OUTPUT=`echo "John Doe" | java NameReader`
```

or

```
OUTPUT=`java NameReader <<< "John Doe"`
```

The trouble with both of these is that $OUTPUT now contains the following:

```
Enter your name: John
```

Because the text that was sent to stdin (and its newline accompanying) isn't reproduced in the output of the program the way we would see it in the console.

Ideally, $OUTPUT would contain this:

```
Enter your name: John Doe
John
```

But I could live with this:

```
Enter your name: 
John
```

(The input is omitted entirely, but the output is on a new line, as expected)

Is there a way in bash (without altering the underlying java program) to get the text that is being piped to stdin to also pipe to stdout at the "time" it's read by the java program, so the full interactive session is captured?

(One more note: Some searching indicated that the spawn/expect commands might be helpful, but the system this will run on does not appear to have them available)

Comment: So what do you see on the console when you say `echo "John Doe" | java NameReader` (no backticks)?

Comment: @n.m., I see the same result: `Enter your name: John` (all on one line)

Comment: You want your script to present you something else, but based on what exactly? How should it know where to insert a newline?

Comment: I would like the output to be exactly what I see when I use the program interactively, which includes what I type on the console (which includes a newline when I hit "enter").

Comment: Interactively? OK. You start a program interactively. How do you know it has asked you a question and it's time to start typing your answer? You want the script to replicate that logic, right? Now answer the same question but imagine the program is printing one character per minute.

Comment: Yep, you understand the problem perfectly.

Comment: Yeah I do thank you very much. Do you? It has no solution. Not a "let's write a quick and dirty bash script" solution at any rate. You need to detect when the program being tested stops and waits for terminal input. You need to distinguish this from "stops and waits for any other kind of event" and from "does a big slow computation right now". In theory you could do it with bash and a few programs installed on your system and lots of effort, but a poor man has to budget his resources properly.

Comment: `script` command is definitely the command you need. See my answer. Thanks for that question because I almost forgot that wonderful command.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `script` command

```
script -q -c "java NameReader" log.txt
```

This will record the input and ouput of the `java NameReader` command in the `log.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

If your java program is like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class A {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println(sc.next());
        }
}
```

then you could build a bash script that would parse an input of the form

```
Enter your name: John
John Doe
```

to transform it into

```
Enter your name: John Doe
John
```

Here is one possible bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
arg1Outpt=`eval "$1"`
javaOut=`echo "$arg1Outpt" | eval "$2"`
#prints Enter your name: John\nJohn Doe      
echo "${javaOut}"$'\n'"${arg1Outpt}" |
                        sed 'N; s/\(Enter your name: \)\(.*\)\(\n\)\(.*\)/\1\4\3\2/'
                        #and this is a multiline sed(man sed) that transforms your 
                        #input into what you want :)
```

use it like this:

```
bash pipeCheat.bash 'echo "john doe"' 'java A'
```

where pipeCheat.bash is the name of the file where you saved the script above.

If you have questions don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing. It's not a complete solution, but it works in this case and may be useful to someone else facing something similar later:

```
{ sleep 3; echo "John Doe" | tee -a out.txt; } | java  NameReader >> out.txt
OUTPUT=`cat out.txt`
rm out.txt
```

This causes the script to do two things in parallel:

1. Wait 3 seconds, then write the text "John Doe" to both the pipe and the file out.txt
2. Run the java program.

By using tee, the text gets written to both the pipe (which the java program is waiting to read), and to the file. The -a option appends the text to the file instead of overwriting it.

The java program also appends its content to out.txt (using >>).

Then we read the file contents into the OUTPUT variable and delete the file.

This isn't really a complete solution, because...

1. It works as long as the java program is running and waiting for the user input within the 3 second sleep. If it's not, then the output will be garbled. While it's reasonable (in this case) to expect the program to be waiting for input after 3 seconds, it's certainly not guaranteed.
2. The 3 second delay makes the process slower than necessary. If the java program was ready for input after only 1 second, then we're spending 2 extra seconds doing nothing. If this were to be run many times, that could add up.
3. It's only really applicable to interactive programs that take a single piece of input. It might be possible to use multiple "sleep/echo/tee" constructs with different sleep lengths to respond to multiple lines, but that seems like it would get both complex and slow very quickly.

...So this is the best I've got for now. Better solutions are still invited, of course.